# Full-text search for Windows share

Tags: windows, gratis, text-search, document-indexing, smb

I have a small laptop with Windows 7.

In Explorer > Network I see a Windows Share `\\BIGSERVER\documents` (SMB/CIFS) which contains all documents of the company (about 1TB of Excel/Word/PowerPoint/PDF files).

In the Windows share, I want to find all documents that contain a particular string of characters (for instance "tube bending").

Is there a tool to do that?

Strict requirements:

- Does not require administrator rights on the client nor on the server.
- Full-text search (inside the documents, not just filenames and metadata).
- Gratis
- Works on Windows 7+

Bonus if:

- Open source.
- Optionally performs OCR on images and images inside documents.
- Creates a local index so that if I want to perform another search in the future it will take less time.

*Non-solutions that require administrator privileges: Agent Ransack, mklink trick.*